# How to do an equation for whether to reboil the kettle full every hour or just boil minimum amounts?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

This is not a homework question! I'm having a discussion with a cost-conscious friend about the merits of reboiling the kettle full vs only boiling minimum amounts. We're both tea-lovers.

**Assume:**

- There is one person using the kettle to boil a cup of tea on the hour from 9am-4pm (8 cups).
- Assume a cup is a metric cup of water (250ml)
- The jug has a maximum capacity for 1.7L and a minimum capacity for 0.7L
- Electricity costs 33 cents per kilowatt-hour
- It takes 60 seconds to boil the jug when full from cold from cold start
- It takes 50 seconds to boil the jug at minimum from cold start

I'd like an equation to describe whether it is better to reboil or to only boil minimum amounts.

I don't know how to describe heat loss over time for this equation - I remember doing differential equations for melting snowballs in school - but I'm not sure how to apply it in this situation.

My question is: **How to do an equation for whether to reboil the kettle full every hour or just minimum amounts?**

Comment: This depends on what happens to the boiled water after it sits for an hour. Does it return to room temperature, or is it still warmer than room temperature an hour later? We can't know this without more information. I'm going to guess that it more or less returns to room temperature, in which case it is more time- and cost-effective to boil the minimum amount every hour (ignoring the time it takes to refill the kettle to 0.7 L).

Comment: You always want to boil the minimum amount. The heat loss is proportional to difference of temperatures - so the hotter your kettle stays over time (that is the more water it contains), the more heat it will lose. The only reason to boil more is if the kettle is more efficient for higher volumes - which is plausible given the time to boil, but I can't come up with the reason for this difference.

Comment: @kccu: no more information is required to answer the question. Boiling more water than is needed wastes energy.

Comment: @RobArthan If the water happened to not lose much heat (say it was placed in a thermos and stayed warm enough to make tea an hour later), then from the information given, time and electricity could be saved by boiling more water than necessary.

Comment: @kccu: good point - I was just thinking about energy efficiency but the question says "cost-conscious".

Comment: I am having trouble finding the reference; the sense is that water boiled for a long time loses something in the way of flavor, I am going to guess air content: note that an ordinary kitchen faucet has an aerator screen. I know that I read this in a book about Chez Panisse, or more likely a review of the book, the tea buyer for the restaurant being Helen Gustafson. I have the book, cannot seem to find this bit. https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1o2s8e/does_water_aeration_affect_beverage_flavor_and_if/

Comment: http://ask.metafilter.com/175486/Tea-nerds-question-about-heating-water-for-tea

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a formal.
It will take more energy to boil the full kettle than the partially full kettle.
SO the first cup uses more energy if you have a full kettle.
The full kettle will lose more energy in the 1 hour between cups because it remains hotter for longer so it gives off more heat.
Think of the water that is not being used to make the tea. If it is on the tap at room temperature it is not losing any heat. If it is sitting in the kettle at a high temperature is is losing heat and therefore losing energy.

Comment: Ok - what if we vary the situation to having a cup of tea every five minutes. Is what you've written still valid?